# how to run eclipse as superuser in ubuntu

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, usb

i have written a java program which access the system file.But it is showing error    `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sys/kernel/debug/usb/usbmon/6u (Permission denied)`

i have change the permission of `6u` to `777` but it is showing same problem again and again.Any help toward this will be helpful.Thanks in advance

Comment: try running `sudo eclipse`.

Answer (score 0):

As comments says if you want any super privilege use "sudo" for running eclipse as a super user go to the directory in which you installed eclipse by using

```
 cd [dir to eclipse] 
 sudo eclipse
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to run eclipse as root user you should do these steps:

```
cd [path of your eclipse directory]
sudo ./eclipse
```